# Replace a field with values specified in another file

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a file that contains the map between the words. I have to refer to that file and replace those words with the mapped ones in some files. For example, below file has the table of words that are mapped  like

```
1.12.2.4               1
1.12.2.7               12
1.12.2.2               5
1.12.2.4               4
1.12.2.6               67
1.12.2.12              5
```

I will have many files that has those key words (1.12.2.*). I want to search for these key words and replace those words with the corresponding mapping taken from this file. How to do this in shell. Suppose a file contains the following lines say

```
The Id of the customer is 1.12.2.12. He is from Grg. 
The Name of the machine is ASB
The id is 1.12.2.4. He is from Psg.
```

After executing the script, the Numbers "1.12.2.12" and "1.12.2.4" should be replaced by 5 and 4 (referred from the master file). Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 9):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } { for (i in array) gsub(i, array[i]) }1' master.txt file.txt
```

Results:

```
The Id of the customer is 5. He is from Grg.
The Name of the machine is ASB
The id is 4. He is from Psg.
```

**To save output to a file:**

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } { for (i in array) gsub(i, array[i]) }1' master.txt file.txt > name_of_your_output_file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

```
FNR==NR { ... }   # FNR is the current record number, NR is the record number
                  # so FNR==NR simply means: "while we process the first file listed
                  # in this case it's "master.txt"
array[$1]=$2      # add column 1 to an array with a value of column 2
next              # go onto the next record

{                 # this could be written as: FNR!=NR
                  # so this means "while we process the second file listed..."
for (i in array)  # means "for every element/key in the array..."
gsub(i, array[i]) # perform a global substitution on each line replacing the key
                  # with it's value if found
}1                # this is shorthand for 'print'
```

**Adding word boundaries makes the matching more strict:**

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } { for (i in array) gsub("\\<"i"\\>", array[i]) }1' master.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Obviously, this will break if the keys in `master.txt` are too similar

Comment: Hi.. I want these values to be written in a file. How can I do this? I am a newbie in shell scripting. Sorry :(.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Actually gsub replaces even if a part of the line matches.. Like suppose mapping file contains entries like 10.1.1.12   1 and the file where I need to change has two entries say. 10.1.1.12 and 10.1.1.1234 then this replaces both the lines.. How to get rid of that?

Comment: @steve: I missed the `next` in the first block, so ignore my previous comment. @user1667630: to match only whole words you can add word boundaries when matching, e.g.: `gsub("\\<" i "\\>", array[i])`; and it might be an idea to only let the first match have effect: `if( gsub("\\<" i "\\>", array[i]) ) break;

Comment: @Thor: Thanks for the excellent suggestion. I was unaware of this syntax :-)

Answer (score 6):

You could have `sed` write a `sed` script for you:

The mappings:

```
cat << EOF > mappings
1.12.2.4               1
1.12.2.7               12
1.12.2.2               5
1.12.2.4               4
1.12.2.6               67
1.12.2.12              5
EOF
```

Input file:

```
cat << EOF > infile
The Id of the customer is 1.12.2.12. He is from Grg. 
The Name of the machine is ASB
The id is 1.12.2.4. He is from Psg.
EOF
```

Generate a script based on the mappings (GNU sed):

```
sed -r -e 's:([^ ]*) +(.*):s/\\b\1\\b/\2/g:' mappings
```

Output:

```sed
s/\b1.12.2.4\b/1/g
s/\b1.12.2.7\b/12/g
s/\b1.12.2.2\b/5/g
s/\b1.12.2.4\b/4/g
s/\b1.12.2.6\b/67/g
s/\b1.12.2.12\b/5/g
```

Evaluate with another `sed` (GNU sed):

```
sed -r -e 's:([^ ]*) +(.*):s/\\b\1\\b/\2/g:' mappings | sed -f - infile
```

Output:

```
The Id of the customer is 5. He is from Grg. 
The Name of the machine is ASB
The id is 1. He is from Psg.
```

Note that the mappings are treated as regular expressions, e.g. a dot (`.`) can mean any character, and may need escaping either in the mappings file or when generating the `sed` script.

Comment: This is not working.. I am getting this error while executing.. sed: -e expression #1, char 26: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Forgot that I have aliased `sed` to `sed -r`. I've added `-r` to the relevant expressions.

Comment: Still I get error.. sed: file - line 1: unknown command: `.' !! Somethig is wrong i guess..

Comment: @user1667630: what version of sed are you using? I just tested this with FreeBSD sed where it works if you replace the `-f -`with `-f /dev/stdin`. As mentioned elsewhere, matching the word boundary of the key is a good idea, so I added it, but now the generated expressions do not work. I think you should try to use GNU sed if you can, often called gsed, it gives you more options.

Comment: In the worst case, save the generated script to a temporary file, run `sed -f /tmp/temporary.sed`, then remove the temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent provided any example,I guess this is what you want:

**Input file**

```
> cat temp
1.12.2.4  1
1.12.2.7  12
1.12.2.2  5
1.12.2.4  4
1.12.2.6  67
1.12.2.12  5
```

**file to be relaced**

```
> cat temp2
The Id of the customer is 1.12.2.12. He is from Grg. 
The Name of the machine is ASB
The id is 1.12.2.4. He is from Psg.
```

**output**

```
> temp.pl
The Id of the customer is 5. He is from Grg. 
The Name of the machine is ASB
The id is 4. He is from Psg

>
```

Below is the perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hsh=();

open (MYFILE, 'temp');
open (MYFILE2, 'temp2');

while (<MYFILE>) {
my@arr = split/\s+/;
$hsh{$arr[0]} = $arr[1];
}
my $flag;
while(<MYFILE2>)
{
$flag=0;
my $line=$_;
foreach my $key (keys %hsh)
{
   if($line=~/$key/)
   {
    $flag=1; 
    $line=~s/$key/$hsh{$key}/g;
    print $line;
   }
}
  if($flag!=1)
  {
  print $line;
  $flag=0;
  }
}
close(MYFILE);
close(MYFILE2);
```