# Replace a string in bash, with a variable based on that string

Tags: bash, sed, ip-address, substitution

I am trying to parse a file for IP addresses and then replace them with a *1 for 1* mapped IP address. For example, find all instances of 1.1.1.1 and replace these with 100.100.1.1, and all instances of 5.5.5.5 and replace those with 100.100.5.5. There may be thousands of IPs, so I do not want to parse the file for each substitution using static **sed** commands.

I am trying to use an *associative array* for this, but I am falling short.

```
echo "1.1.1.1 5.5.5.5" > testfile.txt
declare -A testarray
testarray[ip_1.1.1.1]="100.100.1.1"
testarray[ip_5.5.5.5]="100.100.5.5"
sed -r "s/(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/${testarray[ip_\1]}/g" testfile.txt
```

Using the capture group inside the variable doesn't work. However using the text directly does.

```
sed -r "s/(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/${testarray[ip_1.1.1.1]}/g" testfile.txt
100.100.1.1 100.100.1.1
```

Of course this replaces all IPs with 100.100.1.1, I want to replace based on the array association.

Is there any way to take a capture group and use it in a variable for a replacement in **bash**? I have tried a few variants with *quotes* as well as building a *variable* in advance that still depends on '\1' but it either fails, or just returns the *literal* output of the *variable*. I don't know if there is a better tool than **sed** for this. 
I also tried using variables instead of an array, but I ran into the same issue.

Comment: You are calling the index dinamically with `ip_\1`. That is, using the captured group. This is not possible as you are doing it now, but probably need to use `sed` `e` flag to execute stuff. See for example [this answer by anubhava](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34080390/1983854) for a nice example.

Comment: Perl supports both substitution and associative arrays (hashes). I'd use it instead of sed.

Comment: Thanks for the link @jil, I have not managed to get the linked awk solution to work yet, but I have no experience with Awk so I can't easily tell if this solves the problem. From my reading of it, it may not.

Comment: Don't forget you can use your array to create multiple expressions with the `-e` option with `sed` and change as many or as few IP-pairs as you would like. If the file has 1000 lines, you could conceivably do it in  single call.

Comment: [Replace a field with values specified in another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400217/replace-a-field-with-values-specified-in-another-file) has `sed`, `awk`, & `perl` methods to do this.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX shell script, input is *testfile.txt*, comma seperated "from to" pairs are in *replacements.txt*:

```
echo 1.1.1.1 100.100.1.1 ,5.5.5.5 100.100.5.5 | tr ',' '\n' > replacements.txt
echo "1.1.1.1 6.7.8.9 5.5.5.5" | tr ' ' '\n' > testfile.txt

while read x ; do
    while read a b ; do
        if [ $a = $x ] ; then
            x=$b
            break
        fi
    done < replacements.txt
    echo $x
done < testfile.txt
```

Output:

```
100.100.1.1
6.7.8.9
100.100.5.5
```

Notes:  inefficient, it rereads at least one line of *replacements.txt* for every line of *testfile.txt*, but that does permit replacement lists bigger than **bash**'s available memory.