# Replace dictionary key in string with dictionary value

Tags: python, bash

```
for key in dictionary:
    file = file.replace(str(key), dictionary[key])
```

With this simple snippet I am able to replace each occurence of dictionary key, with it's value, in a file. (Python)

Is there a similar way to go about in bash?

Exampple:

file=`"addMesh:"0x234544"
addMesh="0x12353514"`

```
${!dictionary[i]}: 0x234544
${dictionary[i]}: 0x234544x0


${!dictionary[i]}: 0x12353514
${!dictionary[i]}: 0x12353514x0
```

Wanted output (new content of file):`"addMesh:"0x234544x0"
addMesh="0x12353514x0"`

:

```
for i in "${!dictionary[@]}"
do   
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${dictionary[$i]}"
  echo
done
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what the keys and values look like?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Added

Answer (score 0):

While there certainly are [more sophisticated methods to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400217/replace-a-field-with-values-specified-in-another-file), I find the following much easier to understand, and maybe it's just fast enough for your use case:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create copy of source file: can be omitted
cat addMesh.txt > newAddMesh.txt

file_to_modify=newAddMesh.txt

# Declare the dictionary
declare -A dictionary
dictionary["0x234544"]=0x234544x0
dictionary["0x12353514"]=0x12353514x0

# use sed to perform all substitutions    
for i in "${!dictionary[@]}"
do   
  sed -i "s/$i/${dictionary[$i]}/g" "$file_to_modify"
done

# Display the result: can be omitted
echo "Content of $file_to_modify :"
cat "$file_to_modify"
```

Assuming that the input file `addMesh.txt` contains

```
"addMesh:"0x234544"
addMesh="0x12353514"
```

the resulting file will contain:

```
"addMesh:"0x234544x0"
addMesh="0x12353514x0"
```

This method is not very fast, because it invokes `sed` multiple times. But it does not require `sed` to generate other `sed` scripts or anything like that. Therefore, it is closer to the original Python script. If you need better performance, refer to the answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect equivalent in Bash.  You could do it in a roundabout way, given that `dict` is the associative array:

```
# traverse the dictionary and build command file for sed
for key in "${!dict[@]}"; do
  printf "s/%s/%s/g;\n" "$key" "${dict[$key]}"
done > sed.commands

# run sed
sed -f sed.commands file > file.modified

# clean up
rm -f sed.commands
```